# PHP CLI working but CGI not after compile in (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, pthreads, php-extension

I want to install `PHP 7.0.3` with `Pthreads` Extension. (and another 2 custom extensions `protobuf` & `curve25519`) .

I have done Following step.

```
// Download PHP
cd /usr/local/src
sudo git clone https://github.com/php/php-src.git

// copy pthreads in Php extensions file
sudo cp -r pthreads-3.1.5 php-src/ext/
cd /usr/local/src/php-src

sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr --with-config-file-path=/etc --enable-maintainer-zts
sudo make 
sudo make install
sudo make test

cp php.ini-development /etc/php.ini 

sudo pecl install pthreads    
// Edit /etc/php.ini File
// extension=pthreads.so
```

But Problem is it work fine in command line but not working in Browser (in localhost).

I took References From http://php.net/manual/en/pthreads.installation.php#114837

**NOTE :** i will need Thread Safety Enable in php installation

Answer (score 0):

It should look more like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo su - root

cd /usr/local/src

git clone https://github.com/php/php-src.git php-src
git clone https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads php-src/ext/pthreads

cd php-src
./buildconf --force
./configure --prefix=/usr --with-config-file-path=/etc --enable-maintainer-zts --enable-pthreads=shared

make
make test
make install

cp php.ini-development /etc/php.ini
cp php.ini-development /etc/php-cli.ini

echo "extension=pthreads.so" > /etc/php-cli.ini

/usr/bin/php -v
/usr/bin/php -m
```

You must only load pthreads in CLI.

Comment: Thank you for answare. I did perform those steps. and it also install php with pthread (in cli). but after that PHPis not working with apache2 ( [Check this](http://dmptest007.cloudapp.net/ext.php) ).
And can you please explain me why `pthreads` only load in `CLI` ?